Ghseet BQ connector not refreshing due to "Refresh has already been started"
So I have a few queries running into a gsheet via the bq connector, but there is always this one job that fails to run with an error saying that the refresh has already been started. No queries in the refresh job are the same and I do not have multiple jobs of the same query running concurrently. Very confused on why it keeps on saying that a refresh has already been started. It runs fine if I start the job manually, but keeps on failing if following the schedule.
I tried to reconnect the query, set settings to exclude preview refresh to ensure that the query is unique when running, created a unique identifier for the queries to ensure that they're unique. But all of this don't work. Still kept failing with the same error message. What should I do?
link to error msg
